# Accessing certain libraries in Ogre3D using Code::Blocks IDE

Tags: c++, ogre

I am trying to run the Ogre3D sample game on 64 bit Ubuntu 11.10 Linux using the default GUI build tool in the code::blocks IDE, however, every time I try to build my application, I get the following error messages:
    `ld.bfd.real||cannot find -lOgreMain_d|`
    `ld.bfd.real||cannot find -lOIS_d|`
I am utterly confused, as I have tried everything that leaps to mind.

Comment: Have you installed the Ogre3D development packages from apt? It's looking for libraries to link to that don't exist.

Comment: @JamWaffles I have installed all the packages, and I even searched for and found the files `lOgreMain.so` and `lOIS.so`, but it doesn't seem to like those.

Answer (score 0):

The "wizard" that C::B provided you with apparently links with the *debug* versions of Ogre3D and OIS, hence the _d suffix. You say you have found lOgreMain.so, and lOIS.so, I assume you typo'd here and meant OgreMain.so and OIS.so respectively. In that case, you installed the release version of Ogre3D or the packager ruined the naming convention (naming the Ogre3D debug libs without the _d suffix).

You have two possible solutions: install the debug builds of Ogre3D with the proper suffix, or a much easier fix is to simply link to OgreMain.so and OIS.so. A similar problem was encountered by [this fellow](http://www.rdeeson.com/weblog/105/getting-set-up-with-ogre-3d-on-ubuntu.html), scroll down to:

> So to fix the errors "ld cannot find -lOgreMain_d" and "ld cannot find -lOIS_d" in the Build Messages pane, go to Project > Build options... in the Code::Blocks menu, and change the names of the link libraries shown on the Linker Settings tab for the Debug configuration by removing the _d from the end of both libraries' names: [image]